# Fix Maven dependency conflicts without upgrading the old existing dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, redis

I'm using spring framework 4.2.9.RELEASE and redis 1.7.6.RELEASE:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Lately I had to add a dependency that uses redis 2.2.2.RELEASE that needs Spring 5, So I'm getting dependency conflicts, And I can't upgrade my project to spring 5 and redis 2

What should I do?

Comment: You must decide what to do? Upgrade to Spring 5 ? Or keep on Spring 4? How should I decide for you what to do? My recommendation would be to upgrade to more recent versions of Spring ....but I have only a limited view of your app...

Comment: @khmarbaise I would choose upgrading, but this in out of my control in the meantime, so I need to look for another solution

Comment: What is the dependency you need to add? Try to add as much information as possible to the question

Comment: You can exclude the redis 2.2.2.RELEASE using exclusion tag in the dependency which dependent on 2.2.2.RELEASE version, but it may result in runtime error like noclassdefinitionfound or symbol not found error